# How to assign unique grouping value for each sequence of consecutive True values in pandas boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to generate an appropriate pandas groupBy

Say I have a boolean mask like so `[false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true]`

I would like the groupings to be like so `[0,0,1,0,2,2,0,3,3]`

I can certainly create this array via a loop through the mask but I would like if possible to use the pandas or numpy builtins for ease of use and perhaps vectorization.

(If no builtin exists I would appreciate a more pythonic way of doing this than via a straight loop with a state flag and rank counter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Answer:

```
l = [False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True]

s = pd.Series(l)

s.diff().ne(0).where(s).astype(float).cumsum().fillna(0)
```

Original Answer:

```
l = [False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True]
s = pd.Series(l)
d = s.astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()
d.loc[~(s)] = 0
pd.factorize(d)[0].tolist()
```

Slightly Modified Original Answer (works if first item is True):

```
l = [False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True]
s = pd.Series(l)
d = s.astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()
d.loc[~(s)] = 0
dsort = d.sort_values()
dindex = dsort.index
pd.Series(pd.factorize(dsort)[0],index = dindex).sort_index().tolist()
```

Alternative way:

Generate List and put into series.

```
l = [False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True]
s = pd.Series(l)
```

Find items that are sequential

```
d = s.astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum().reset_index()
```

Locate the first `True` in each group

```
d.loc[s].groupby(0)['index'].first().rename_axis(None)
```

Factorize new grouping and put into series

```
f = pd.factorize(d.loc[s].groupby(0)['index'].first().rename_axis(None))
s2 = pd.Series(f[0]+1,index = f[1])
```

Use reindex and forward fill all the missing spaces. Fill any NaN's with 0. Lastly replace all places that were `False` with zeros.

```
s2 = s2.reindex(s.index).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
s2.loc[~(s)] = 0
s2.tolist()
```

Comment: I edited my answer to account for if the first item was True. You might also be able to use the first solution and sort first before using `factorize`

Answer (score 2):

OP here, see the accepted answer.

I just spent sometime with it and wanted to say a word about how it works so hopefully it will come a bit easier to the next reader who wants to work it out.

Here is the code for reference:

```
l = [False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True]
s = pd.Series(l)
d = s.astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()
d.loc[~(s)] = 0
pd.factorize(d)[0].tolist()
```

The key code pieces are the `diff` followed by the `ne(0)` followed by the `cumsum()`

Here are the key insights.

`diff`:
After the diff, the array will take on the following values:

The first value will take on `NAN` (because there is no preceding value to diff it with) and thereafter every True will take on a `1` if it follows a `False` or 0 if it follows another `True`.

So all but one sequence of `True` values will look like this:

`1, 0, 0, 0`

Or, when a sequence of `True` begins with the first element in the array

`NAN, 0, 0, 0`

(Nearly the same logic applies to the sequences of `False` values but we normalize those at the end with the `d.loc[~(s)] = 0` statement)

`ne(0)` normalizes NAN and 1 because they both `!=` 0.

`cumsum()` assigns a value (equal to one greater than the previous) to the first `True` in the sequence of `True` values that carries forward for all the other True values that are part of its sequence group (since their value from the `diff` call is `0`).

So now we have what we want, with all sequences of `True` values in the series mapped to a unique integer.

Then we make the call to `d.loc[~(s)] = 0` which assigns all the `False` values to group 0.

We could stop here (without making the `pd.factorize` call) which would output `[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 4, 0, 6, 6]` for the `[False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True]` I posited in the question, but to get the output to match the output I stipulated in the question, you need to call `pd.factorize`

A word of caution for calling `pd.factorize`:

If the first value in the input array is `True` rather than `False` you will not have the `False` values mapping to the zero group, which in my use case recommended doing without making that call.

Answer (score 0):

If using `skimage` library is not an issue, You can do this:

```
from skimage import measure
l = [False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True]
labels = measure.label(np.array(l))
```

```
out: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
```